# MySQL LIMIT doesn't work in Prestashop module

Tags: mysql, prestashop, limit

I have written a query for use in a Prestashop 1.6 module and was surprised to see that `LIMIT` doesn't work in the query. The plan is to get the top 10 best seller products.

I have tested it in phpMyAdmin and it works perfectly, but when in the application it doesn't work. Following is the query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT id_product, sale_nbr 
       FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_sale 
       WHERE id_product = '.(int)$id_product.' 
       ORDER BY sale_nbr DESC LIMIT 10';

return Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
```

I have also tried `LIMIT 0, 10`

There are no error messages the `LIMIT` is simply not working. In my test example 15 of the 50 products in my list are top sellers, but I want only 10 of them to show, but it always comes out as 15.

Comment: Please post your complete codes

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try nesting:

```
sql = 'SELECT id_product, sale_nbr FROM (
       SELECT id_product, sale_nbr 
       FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_sale 
       WHERE id_product = '.(int)$id_product.' 
       ORDER BY sale_nbr DESC LIMIT 10 ) t1';
```

Comment: Thank you Bobert1234, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you use to execute your query.
Using:

```
- Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql) => Returns 1 result
- Db::getInstance()-> getRow($sql) => Returns an array with the first result line
- Db::getInstance()-> executes($sql) => Returns an array of results
```

With the 3rd way you should be able to use the limit; More info here : https://www.prestashop.com/fr/blog/les-bonnes-pratiques-de-la-classe-db-sur-prestashop-1-5

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am using the 3rd way - executeS, but I still cannot get the limit to work!

Comment: Could you put the complete code snippet so we can watch.

Comment: Ok try with : 

$sql = 'SELECT id_product, sale_nbr 
       FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_sale 
       ORDER BY sale_nbr DESC LIMIT 10';

        return Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql); It's ok for me :)

Comment: its' oK for you ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work, LIMIT is still not working.

Comment: try in a blank page at the root, just include the config file (include ('config / config.inc.php') and then put the piece of code that I sent to you.I just got the test is If it does not work you have another problem.

Comment: Assuming I have done it correctly, the result I get is a blank screen.

Comment: replace return by dump for try. And active error/debug

Comment: Following is the result. I changed the limit to 2 to reduce the array size. It gives the same result as phpMyAdmin, a correct result. array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_product' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sale_nbr' => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_product' => string '7' (length=1)
      'sale_nbr' => string '6' (length=1)

Comment: so it works in a page at the root, but not in your code?

Comment: In your page replace the return with a dump

Comment: I am getting the same result as above for every product even those not in the top 10. If I add the WHERE id_product = '.(int)$id_product.' the results are correct for each product in the top 10, and for the products not in the top 10 I get an empty array. But the LIMIT is still not working. I think this is not a LIMIT problem I think it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

To get top 10 best seller products :

```
 $sql = new DbQuery();
 $sql->select('SELECT id_product, sale_nbr');
 $sql->from('product_sale', 'ps');
 $sql->orderBy('`sale_nbr` DESC');
 $sql->limit(10);
 return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executes($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, and your code does work, but I believe the problem is not with the LIMIT but something else.